# How to get the same running countdown timer from one HTML page to another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, timer

My first page has JavaScript countdown timer and displays the timer in a div. It works.

**page1.html**

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="time" >
    
</div>

  <script>
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I have tried to get the div element from page1.html to a div in page2.html, using Ajax through JavaScript functions. But page2.html is not showing the same live countdown timer.

Question: How to get working countdown timer from the div of page1.html to the div in page2.html. Also, how do I put it in a div inside an `li` element in page2.html.

**page2.html**

```html
<html>
<body>
  
<div id="countdownResult">
   
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function autoRefresh_countdown()
{
    $("#countdownResult").load("http://localhost:1880/div #time");// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
      
}

  setInterval('autoRefresh_countdown()', 2000);
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you already try using websockets? I'm just guessing but I think it could work for what you want to do.

Comment: Given that you don't know how long the call will take, then you need to time it. If both pages are on the same system and you can guarantee that the clock will not be reset during the call, then you can send the current time value from page 1 with the current count down value, then get the current time value on page 2 and adjust the count down for the elapsed time. Probaby won't work across different systems though due to different clock settings.

Comment: thanks for your replies.

Comment: is there any examples how to do it with websockets, i have no idea how to do it, if you can please help me. i am new on this issue. thanks

Comment: the moment page1 unloads (use `window.unload` to detect page unload) store the timer value in `localStorage` and load it on page load in page2 and continue timer.

Comment: You should use a Server language with AJAX for backward compatibility.